# Generating n-grams with foldl in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, fold

So I'm fiddling with Racket. Recursively generating n-grams from a list of words was pretty straightforward:

```
(define (n-grams-recursive words n)
  (if (< (length words) n)
      '()
      (cons (take words n) (n-grams-recursive (cdr words) n))))
```

And the iterative version also pretty straightforward:

```
(define (n-grams words n)
  (define (iter n-grams remaining-words)
    (if (< (length remaining-words) n)
        n-grams
        (iter (cons (take remaining-words n) n-grams)
              (rest remaining-words))))
  (iter '() words))
```

But how would I do the iterative version with one of the fold functions? I know it must be possible but I have been struggling with it for a while to no avail. I know the first arg to fold should be a function that takes 2 arguments; the result list and the input list at each stage of iteration, and do the taking and consing in there, but I keep running into problems with cons hitting non-pairs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `for/fold`:

```
(define (n-grams/fold words n)
  (for/fold ([n-grams '()] [remaining-words words])                
            ([_ (in-naturals)] ; loop forever
             #:break (< (length remaining-words) n))
    (values (cons (take remaining-words n) n-grams)
            (rest remaining-words))))
```

And here is one using `foldl`:

```
(struct state (n-grams remaining-words) #:transparent)

(define (n-grams/foldl words n)
  (foldl (λ (_ s)
           (match-define (state n-grams remaining-words) s)
           (if (< (length remaining-words) n)
               s
               (state (cons (take remaining-words n) n-grams)
                      (rest remaining-words))))
         (state '() words)
         words))
```

Note that `foldl` is not a natural fit for this problem. The best solution is your original one.

The problem with `foldl` is that you only get one element of the list at a time (and you need the `n` first elements). That means you need to keep track of both the n-grams and the remaining-words. To keep track to two things at once, the solution above use a struct.

Uddate: If the subblists are generated ahead of time, the solution becomes:

```
(define (sublists xs)
  (if (empty? xs)
      '()
      (cons xs (sublists (rest xs)))))

(define (n-grams/foldl2 words n)
  (foldl (λ (remaining-words n-grams)
           (if (< (length remaining-words) n)
               n-grams
               (cons (take remaining-words n)
                     n-grams)))
         '()
         (sublists words)))

(n-grams/foldl2 '(a b c d e) 2)
```